# How can I make my script work/respond

Tags: javascript

I am on PC and not using localhost or anything, just made a .html and started trying. I have linked scripts in head both by "src" and by "href", because I downloaded them, but they still don't work. I went on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJogzz and it is working perfectly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <link type="text/css"href="./Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/javascript"href="./Style.js" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <span class="about" id="but01">Click on me 1</span>
    <span class="about" id="but02">Click on me 2</span>

    <div id="s1" class="hidden" id="draggable-element">
        <div id="draggable-element">Text here</div>
    </div>

    <div id="s2" class="hidden">2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #101010;
    color: #ff9900;
}

.hidden{
    display:none;
}

[draggable=true] {
    cursor: move;
}
#draggable-element {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ff9900;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
// Makes div dissapear on click on div
    $('span[id^="but0"]').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
            if($('#s' + id).is(':visible'))
                 $('#s' + id).hide();
            else
                $('#s' + id).show();
    });



var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing your script at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

And as you're using jQuery, i recommend wrapping your code inside a `$(document).ready()` function (not needed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css"href="./Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<span class="about" id="but01">Click on me 1</span>
<span class="about" id="but02">Click on me 2</span>

<div id="s1" class="hidden" id="draggable-element">
    <div id="draggable-element">Text here</div>
</div>

<div id="s2" class="hidden">2</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

this code works for me. you definitly not need a server for javascript

Comment: the script is in the exact same folder as the html file?
no subfolder or anything?

Comment: yeah it is in same folder, I tried to make the element work and then copy to the right place

Comment: the JS code you've added in codepen is the "script.js", right?
As it works in the codePen there must be a problem with your folder structure. Remove those script imports in the <head> tag, as they are not needed ->[ my codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mErwLy).
Can you please show us your folder structure

Comment: Picture of my folder structure: https://gyazo.com/6381af07ae07becb92185f061c232bf6

Comment: Also, Style.css and Style.js files are linked the same way and they location is the same, Style.css is working and Style.js  is not.

Comment: and you load them inside the body element at the very bottom?

Comment: is there something in the devtools console?
or look at the network tab: is there a 404 not found error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a webserver to load JS files. This resource might be useful. > https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: This is what it shows in devtools, https://gyazo.com/f46b23afbc36f483c5b892325469cdf5

Comment: I've just created all your files and it works just fine, if i add the script.js at the bottom of the body element.
make sure there are no errors in the console

Comment: You mean you add the script.js inside the script tags?

Comment: have a look at the new code i've edited. This works for me just fine.
I've removed style.js as i dont have it.
Try it like this and if it works, add style.js again

Comment: where can i take a look at your code you have edited??

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!
As you were loading the javascript in head tag, the dom was not rendered yet.
So the script did not recognize the elements and therefore returned null. The script then failed. As you now load the javascript at the end of the file. The elements are rendered and the script recognizes them and can add some actions. Please mark your question as solved

Comment: This helped a lot. How can I mark the question? I am new on this website. And also is there a "rep" or similar button or setting that users give to each  other as a thanks when the question is solved?

Comment: Next to my post on the left site should be an icon "mark as solved".
Click it. You can also upvote my answer. Yes there is a way, i just read about it. But you have to few rep for that function. it's called bounty. Mark it as solved thats fair enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's simple HTTP server to host the files. A script tag wont load as the file system wont respond to a GET request.

Ensure you have Python 2.x installed, then run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

In the terminal, from within the directory the files are saved:

```
cd /path/to/files
```

You will then be able to access the files at:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

Alternatively you can launch Chrome to allow access to local files with:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally).

If you want to avoid those options. Put the JS inline on the HTML document within script tags. Like in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXowVp).